# html parse jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I;ve got troubles coding a function.
Here's the situation :
I've got divs like that :

```
<div class='sound'>
  <img src='$artwork' class='artwork' />
  <div>
    <p class='genre'>$genre</p>
    <p class='title'>$title</p>
    <i href ="$link" class='link'></i>
  </div>
<div class="sound' ... ...
```

and many others like that.

I'd like to make a button that get all the divs the content with the classname 'sound'
and use this with this function of the player's API :

```
$.fullwidthAudioPlayer.addTrack(trackUrl, title, meta, cover, linkUrl);
```

I tried this function in jquery, it gets the datas not parsed :

```
$('.sound').each(function() {
    $.fullwidthAudioPlayer.addTrack($('.content',this).text());
```

So, I'd like to know the right way to do it !

Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: Where in the div do you expect to get trackUrl, title, meta, cover, and linkUrl?  I think title is the most obvious, but the others are not.

Comment: trackURL matches with $link; title with $title, meta with $genre, cover with $artwork, and linkUrl is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query for each one separately:

```
var trackUrl = $('.link', this).attr('href'),
    title = $('.title', this).text(),
    meta = $('.genre', this).text(),
    cover = $('.artwork', this).attr('src'),
    linkUrl = null;
$.fullwidthAudioPlayer.addTrack(trackUrl, title, meta, cover, linkUrl);
```